# CNN model not able to make prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, predict

I trained a `CNN` model successfully, however I am getting errors when I feed images to the model for it to predict the labels.

This is my model (I am restoring it with `saver.restore`)...

```
# load dataset
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# interactive session
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# data and labels placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

# 32 filters of size 5x5 and 32 biases,
# the filters are used to create 32 feature maps
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_img = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

# first layer activated using a Relu activation function
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_img, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
pool1 = max_pool_2x2(conv1)

# 64 filters of size 5x5
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

# second layer
conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
pool2 = max_pool_2x2(conv2)

# fully connected layer with 1024 neurons
W_fully = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fully = bias_variable([1024])

pool2flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
fully = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(pool2flat, W_fully) + b_fully)

# dropout layer removes dead neurons
prob_drop = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
dropout = tf.nn.dropout(fully, prob_drop)

# readout layer that will return the raw values
# of our predictions
W_readout = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_readout = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(dropout, W_readout) + b_readout

# loss function
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_conv, labels=y))

# restore the trained CNN model
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model2.ckpt")
```

`y_conv` is the predictor.

The model is trained on the `mnist` dataset, now I have an image of a number and I want the model to tell me what it thinks it is in terms of accuracy. I tried the following...

```
prediction = tf.argmax(y_conv, 1)
print(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x:two_images[0]}))
```

After feeding the image `two_images[0]` to the model, I got the following error...

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (784,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'

So I fixed it by doing the following...

```
prediction = tf.argmax(y_conv, 1)
print(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x:two_images[0].reshape((1, 784))}))
```

But now I am getting a whole bunch of errors that I cannot decipher...

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float
>        [[Node: Placeholder_2 = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

This is how I populate the variable `two_images`...

```
# extract the indices of the number 2
two_idxs_list = np.where(mnist.test.labels[:, 2].astype(int) == 1)
two_idxs = two_idxs_list[0][:10]

# use the indices to extract the images of 2 and their corresponding label
two_images = mnist.test.images[two_idxs]
two_labels = mnist.test.labels[two_idxs]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay with the code added I was able to test in on my machine. The issue is that your network expects **two** inputs, one image, and **a label**. Even if you only do inference, you have to supply an input, maybe just some zeroes? Obviously the loss calculation will be wrong, but you're not interested in that, only in the prediction. So your sess.run line should be:

```
print( sess.run( prediction, feed_dict= {
    x: two_images[0].reshape((1, 784)),
    y: np.zeros( shape = ( 1, 10 ), dtype = np.float32 ) } ) )
```

Comment: Ok I will clarify a little bit. I imported the mnist dataset as so `mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)` and all I did was extract an image of a 2 from the dataset. Now, I tried converting the image as you suggested and I get the following error `TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.`

Comment: Updated my answer. You can't use tf.to_float _before_ feeding the data through the feed_dict.

Comment: So that's what I did but I still get the same error as before. It is telling me I cannot feed a `tf.Tensor` object.

Comment: Please share the code where the `two_images` variable is populated.

Comment: Ok I was on the wrong track, I'm adding another answer.

Comment: Ended up updating my answer, pls check

Comment: this is good, I am getting the prediction, but what I really want is to show the accuracy in terms of percentage of how sure the model thinks a label is correct. What this prints out is the predicted label. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Right now your prediction is `tf.argmax( y_conv, 1 )`, which gives you the _index_ (=label) of the element with the highest predicted probability. `confidence_in_prediction = tf.reduce_max( y_conv, 1 )` will give you the _value_.